# schedule Data flow via cloud scheduler and cloud functions using dataflow-flex-template.json

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a java maven project and I have built a docker image and created a flex template using the following commands.

`mvn clean install`

Build and push the template in Artifact Registry of GCP using command:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://<BUCKET_PATH_WITH_FOLDER>/dataflow-template.json --image-gcr-path="<ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_PATH>/dataflow:latest" --sdk-language=JAVA --flex-template-base-image=JAVA11 --jar="<FULL_PATH_OF_YOUR_CLONED_FOLDER>\target\pipeline-<VERSION>.jar" --env=FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS="com.example.MyPipeline"
```

Deploy the template in Dataflow of GCP using command:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "data-pipeline" --template-file-gcs-location="gs://<BUCKET_PATH_WITH_FOLDER>
```

This "gcloud dataflow flex-template run" creates data flow and my job is working fine. now I want to schedule this for every 10 minutes.

I have done research and I found I can able to create cloud functions and inside cloud functions if I use `gcloud dataflow flex-template run "data-pipeline" --template-file-gcs-location="gs://<bucket>/templates/template.json` and schedule via cloud scheduler.

```
import subprocess
    def execute_gcloud():
        print("Cloud Function triggered: Starting the job")
    
        gcloud_command = "gcloud dataflow flex-template run 'data-poc-new' --template-file-gcs-location='gs://<bucket>/templates/template.json'"
        print("Executing gcloud command:", gcloud_command)
    
        try:
            # Run the gcloud command using subprocess
            subprocess.run(gcloud_command, shell=True, check=True)
            print("gcloud command execution completed successfully")
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("Error executing gcloud command:", e)
    
        print("Cloud Function execution completed")
```

But am unable to test or run this because gcloud not found or some auth issues e.t.c. in cloud functions

I tried creating a bash file and wrote the mvn command in the bash file and stored it in gcs.
I tried to create a scheduler by adding a bash file as basg gcs url but no data flow created and nothing happened.

please suggest me any step by step approach to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? Also are you using the updated version of Cloud SDK CLI? References: [Google Cloud Command Line Interface (gcloud CLI)](https://cloud.google.com/cli) And recommended installation [Install the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)